# How to shift rows up in Pandas Dataframe based on specific column

Tags: python, pandas

How do I shift up all the values in a row for one specific column without affecting the order of the other columns?

For example, let's say i have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
data= {'ColA':["A","B","C"],
        'ColB':[0,1,2],
        'ColC':["First","Second","Third"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
```

I would see the following output:

```
  ColA  ColB    ColC
0    A     0   First
1    B     1  Second
2    C     2   Third
```

In my case I want to verify that Column B does not have any 0s and if so, it is removed and all the other values below it get pushed up, and the order of the other columns are not affected. Presumably, I would then see the following:

```
  ColA  ColB    ColC
0    A   1     First
1    B   2    Second
2    C   NaN   Third
```

I can't figure out how to do this using either the drop() or shift() methods.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I'd do this IIUC is to filter out the values in `ColB` which are not `0`, and fill the column with these values according to the length of the obtained valid values:

```
m = df.loc[~df.ColB.eq(0), 'ColB'].values
df['ColB'] = float('nan')
df.loc[:m.size-1, 'ColB'] = m

print(df)

 ColA  ColB    ColC
0    A   1.0   First
1    B   2.0  Second
2    C   NaN   Third
```

Answer (score 2):

Let us do simple `sorted`

```
invalid=0
df['ColX']=sorted(df.ColB,key=lambda x : x==invalid)
df.ColX=df.ColX.mask(df.ColX==invalid)
df
Out[351]: 
  ColA  ColB    ColC  ColX
0    A     0   First   1.0
1    B     1  Second   2.0
2    C     2   Third   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can swap *0s* for *nans* and then move up the rest of the values:

```py
import numpy as np
df.ColB.replace(0, np.nan, inplace=True)
df.assign(ColB=df.ColB.shift(df.ColB.count() - len(df.ColB)))
```